# Zero trace matrix, product of symetric and antisymetric matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

It is well-known that every square matrix can be written as the sum of a symetric matrix and an antisymetrix matrix.

The same does not hold for the product : for example, matrices $M\in\mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$) with $\text{tr}(M)\neq 0$ or non singular $M$ with odd $n$ cannot be written as $S\times A$ with $S\in\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{K})$ and
$A\in\mathscr{A}_n(\mathbb{K})$.

One easily checks that if $n=2$ and $M\in\mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ has zero trace, then it can be written as $S\times A$ with $S\in\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{K})$ and
$A\in\mathscr{A}_n(\mathbb{K})$.

My question is : does this result hold for even $n=4,6,8,...$ ?

Comment: You need more than trace zero, you need the characteristic polynomial to be even.

Comment: Nice. How do you prove the necessary and the not sufficient conditions ?

Comment: If $M=SA$, then $M^T=-AS$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $-SA=-M$. But $M$ and $M^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial…

Comment: I see, thank you. And if I assume moreover the characteristic polynomial to be even, does the decomposition $M=SA$ exist ?

Comment: No, I think it’s still insufficient. If $M$ is nonsingular and its characteristic polynomial is even, then, if $M=SA$, $-M^T=A(SA)A^{-1}$ is similar to $M$. Since by Jordan decomposition $M^T$ is similar to $M$, this implies that $M$ must be similar to $-M$.  Consider for instance $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. A necessary and sufficient condition seems hard to be found.